# Bind XAML Map control to Code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

EXPLANATION:
I can't use code behind because I'm using some interfaces who hare injected with Ninject, I can't just do service = new service() because there are a lot more dependencies behind that one. As for the question about the type name as a converter parameter, I found this solution best for binding my model to my UI. I use this for all of my modules and is working great. Just my Map control is not working at all.

Atm I'm trying to include a Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map control in my Windows Phone 8 app. But I can't seem to get it working.

Because of Dependency injection and stuff I can't use the code behind of my xaml page. So I made myself a MapController who is linked to the Xaml as a DataContext. But I got some problems with it.

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DynamicLocator}, Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}, ConverterParameter='BaseCpr.Plugins.ShopLocator.Model.MapController,BaseCpr.Plugins'}">

    <Grid>
         <maps:Map DataContext="{Binding MapControl, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </maps:Map>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MapController:

```
public MapController(IService Service) {
    //Service is used here a lot

    MapControl = new Map() {
        CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Road,
        Heading = 0,
        Pitch = 0,
        ZoomLevel = 7,
        Center = new GeoCoordinate(50.50, 4.000)
    };
}

private Map mapControl;
public Map MapControl {
    get { return mapControl; }
    set {
        if (mapControl != value) {
            mapControl = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MapControl);
        }
    }
}
```

The link between the XAML and my MapController is working (tested it with simple boolean bindings). And when I'm debugging the getter of MapControl get called. But my map on my screen is still at the default view. Can someone help me out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT 2:** (some more info)
In my MapController I have the following function as well:

```
public async void getPhoneLocation() {
    try
    {
        //getting location and put it in geoposition

        var cord = new GeoCoordinate(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);
        MapControl.SetView(cord, 16, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);
        CreateAndAddUserMarker(cord);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

This is why I can't just bind all Map properties of my XAML map control. I need to call the SetView() function as well. I also need to add Layers to my map to add pins on the map. getPhoneLocation() is called in the MapController constructor.

Comment: You're setting the maps:Map DataContext to an instance of Map.  This isn't how this works.  This isn't how any of this works.  And the type name as a converter parameter?  Wuuuut?  You need to step back, as none of this is correct.  What do you need to do with the Map?  What limitations do you face that prevent using codebehind?  [Edit] and add these details to the top of your question.  Answers will be solutions to this, rather than trying to fix what you have (fixing it isn't possible).

Comment: So what should I bind to then if it's not a Map instance?

Comment: You should expose the services via INPC properties in your ViewModel, then bind those to DependencyProperties on your Window, and go to town on them in your codebehind, most likely.  But I'm not sure if that's your real issue as my reading comprehension is poor.

Comment: Well in my Map Controller I can call a RaisePropertyChanged() to let my UI know it has changed. But for some reason my map control is not changing as I would expect. My binding itself is working I'm just not sure if it's also working for a Map control.

Comment: Because you can't bind a Map control to a property of type Map and expect the Map instance to be switched out.  That's not how bindings work.  I don't even think you could bind the Map to the Content property of a ContentControl.  And if by some miracle it worked reliably, it wouldn't be the correct way to solve your problems.

Comment: Well, when I change my map to: <maps:Map ZoomLevel="{Binding ModelZoomLevel}" /> and then add a property of int ModelZoomLevel to my MapController the zoom level get adjusted when ModelZoomLevel changes. So I can control my Map control. The problem is I need to call some functions on my map control as well (setView(), ...). That's why I need a Map property in my MapController

Comment: That's easy enough to accomplish.  The problem is that your question doesn't contain any information about when and why you need to call SetView.  Again, read my first comment.  Detail what you need to accomplish and why you can't do it (can't use a binding to call an event seems to be your issue there), and someone can tell you how to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem by making a MapBehavior and bind a ViewModel property to a  Dependency Property from the MapBehavior. 
That way, when my Location get's updated it will fire the Dependency Property PropertyChangedCallback.

```
 public DependencyProperty LocationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Location", typeof(GeoCoordinate), typeof(MapBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.NewValue != null && args.NewValue != args.OldValue)
    {
        var sendMap = ((MapBehavior)sender);
        sendMap.AssociatedObject.SetView((GeoCoordinate)args.NewValue, 14, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);
    }
}));
```

In sender is the Map control, that way the SetView() method on your MapControl can be used :)

It took me a while to get this solution so I wanted to share it anyway